Stack Drone Images like in Astro photography, but all with all RGB channels
My Problem
I am looking for a way, to do image preprocessing similar to astro photography, but with all RGB channels and without aligning and stacking in astro-software. I would like to do the stacking in Affinity Photo. I am working on my Apple-Silicone Mac.
My Question
What is the least inconvenient solution for this Problem?
Background / What I tried so far:
I would like to do night time photography with my drone (dji mini 3 pro). The challenges are a noisy chip and some movement in the camera, since it hangs up in the air.
I tried to solve those problems with taking many exposures (~100 maybe) at fixed camera settings and stack them afterwards. I did the stacking with Affinity Photo (non-astro stacking process) and got surprisingly good results. But I would like to improve image quality by subtracting bias and dark frames, like in astro photography. Flat Frame Processing might also be nice, but I do not consider it necessary.
Also some (semi-) automated process to drop blurry images would be nice. But to my knowledge there is nothing suitable.
As far as I can see, the usual astro photo stacking software is specialised to monochromatic images and does a really bad job at aligning non-astro photos.

Astro stacking is not limited to BW images. You might be right that it doesn't perform well on non-astro images though.
DeepSkyStacker can align and stack colour images, and it can drop blurred ones based on a quality threshold. Have you tried it?
For Macs, Astro Pixel Processor (requires a license) and Siril (free) both stack. Siril is multiplatform and offered also for Arm Macs.
This video shows how to stack video frames of the Moon to get a single photo using ASI Studio:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7z9ET0hpVY
Of course converting video into single images gives you the freedom to pick any stacking software you like, while using video as is is more limiting but saves disk space.
For info: bias and dark frame are rarely if ever needed with modern dSLR (it can also worsen the results), but drones may be different. I don't know but don't assume you need them. My guess is that bias are completely useless, dark  maybe still help. More info on ClarkVision, here and here.
If you find out that astro software actually doesn't work on non-astro photos, then you need to convert the video into single images and use Hugin with this tutorial.

Thanks for your Answer. DeepSkyStacker is not an option, because it is not available on Mac and virtualisation does not work because there is ARM instead of x86 in my computer.
I have not yet tried to work with Video, because RAW photos seemed more promising to me. But I will have a look at it.

Then check Astro Pixel Processor and Siril
